# Chaning Swappiness value with an SSD and Low Ram is it worth it?

Tags: ram, swap

I've been told that if you want your system to be fast, you should lowered your swappiness value to a minium (usually 10%) because usually the RAM is faster than a Hardrive, but in my case I have only 2.9 Usable RAM, and an SSD of 120gb (ubuntu partition is 55 GB and swap partition is arround 3.3 Gb... I don't know if this helps but I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome (try to avoid it because it tortures my computer a lot [resources heavy]), LXQT (it takes a lot longer to kill my computer) and KDE-Plasma (not as RAM hungry as Gnome, but this one lolves to eat CPU resources, so it's the same almost), by default I'm usin LXQT for long-term use.

So...

It's really worth it to lower my default swappiness value of 60% to speed up my machine?

Comment: Even on an SSD, swap is *slow*, and changing swappiness usually does not make a big difference from the human's perspective waiting for their mouse click to be recognized, The most worthwhile option is usually to add more RAM. However, your system is different from mine, so feel free to experiment and see for yourself.

Comment: @user535733 I have installed 4Gb of RAM but my motherboard only supports 3Gb so I have 1 floating Gb of RAM I can't use :^) adding more RAM is not a solution for me :c is an 12 years old Laptop XD that the main reason I use linux, because windows in long term takes more resources specially when I customized it  with all the shit I love XDD

Comment: Poor performance is expected with Gnome and less than 3GB of RAM. Ubuntu is NOT designed with old equipment in mind, though some flavors (like Lubuntu) can be so used. Please avoid profanity on AskUbuntu.

Comment: In my times Ubuntu only required 512mb of RAM, now the minium is 1.5Gb, and yes they are other OS's that could help me out, Zorin OS uses less recourses is Ubuntu based and uses Gnome, I could always go to Lubuntu with XFCE but that' not what I asked XDD

thank for anwering anyway :'v

Comment: You are getting really pasive-aggresive, please avoid being rude :C